# How to plot two different line graphs in R with different ranges using points()

Tags: r, date, points

I have the following code, and all I can graph is the "red" line (unemployement). If anyone could help that would be great. Thank you:

```
library(lubridate) 

data<-read.csv("BLSdata.csv") 
summary(data) 

data$DATE <- as.date(mdy(data$Date)) 
class(data$DATE) 
data$DATE <- mdy(as.character(data$Date)) 
data$DATE 


plot(data$DATE, data$Unemployed, type="l", lwd=2, col="red",xlab="Year", 
     ylab="Jobs", ylim=c(6000,17000)) 

points(data$DATE, data$Employed, type="l", lwd=2, col="green")
```

GOAL: I am trying to graph both green and red lines on a graph with one axis.

Comment: Are the values of `data$Employed` within your `ylim`?

Comment: Can you describe what you're getting instead of both lines on one graph? Also, are the date$Employed values within the ylim you set in the plot() call? If they aren't, the points might just be off the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use `lines()` instead of `points()`, but that won't matter because you put in `type="l"`.  The main thing is to force the range to include both sets of data:

```
plot(data$DATE, data$Unemployed, type="l", lwd=2, col="red",xlab="Year", 
     ylab="Jobs", ylim=range(c(data$Unemployed,data$Employed))) 

lines(data$DATE, data$Employed, lwd=2, col="green")
```